# How to use ArcGIS 10.2 Features to JSON output in web maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, features, json, arcgis-10.2

Using the Features to JSON tool that is now available with 10.2, is there additional formatting that needs to be done to the files before they can be displayed as web maps?

Comment: where are you wanting to display these webmaps? please elaborate more on your use case.

Comment: I'm using leaflet

Comment: I am using http://geojson.io/ to test my geojson file. even using http://mapshaper.org/ to create a geojson doesn't give me an output that will upload to the http://geojson.io/ site

Comment: probably a format issue, esri is going to create esrijson if you don't use a tool to make it any different. I know there are several geojson types. id dyou try loading it to ArcGIS.com?

Comment: I don't think json or geojson are supported file types for arcgis online

Comment: you may be right in that esri hasn't given a button for import.  however ArcGIS.com only displays webmaps (esrijson) and I have pulled a json string from a webmap on ArcGIS.com. the put will be the part I don't know about. but that is why this is in the comments not the answer section.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I saw a tweet the other day about this GeoJSON Import / Export tool:
https://github.com/jasonbot/geojson-madness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Features to JSON outputs ArcGIS JSON geometries, you'd have to use something like [Terraformer](https://github.com/Esri/Terraformer) to convert to GeoJSON if you intended on working with the data as a client-side graphics layer in Leaflet.

edit: 30/9/15
Esri's open source [Leaflet plugins](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) make it easy to fetch data dynamically from ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Online and display in Leaflet.